# Docker compose getting stuck

Tags: apache, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm quite new with Docker and I'm trying to use `docker-compose` in order to set up Apache with PostgreSQL all together.

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:

    db:
      image: postgres

    apache2:
        image: webdevops/apache:latest
        ports:
            - 8084:80
            - 443:443
        links:
            - db
```

And every time I execute `docker-compose up`, it usually gets stuck in

```
AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND -D APACHE_LOCK_DIR'
```

This is the output when I execute it.

First gets stuck with some `LOG:  autovacuum launcher started` while installing postgres, and when I Ctrl+C it, and re-execute docker-compose, it get stuck in the `apache2 -D FOREGROUND -D APACHE_LOCK_DIR` line.

Here is the ouput

```
 docker-compose up
Pulling db (postgres:latest)...
latest: Pulling from library/postgres
cd0a524342ef: Pull complete
9c784d04dcb0: Pull complete
d99dddf7e662: Pull complete
e5bff71e3ce6: Pull complete
cb3e0a865488: Pull complete
31295d654cd5: Pull complete
fc930a4e09f5: Pull complete
8650cce8ef01: Pull complete
61949acd8e52: Pull complete
527a203588c0: Pull complete
26dec14ac775: Pull complete
0efc0ed5a9e5: Pull complete
40cd26695b38: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:fd6c0e2a9d053bebb294bb13765b3e01be7817bf77b01d58c2377ff27a4a46dc
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:latest
Pulling apache2 (webdevops/apache:latest)...
latest: Pulling from webdevops/apache
aafe6b5e13de: Pull complete
0a2b43a72660: Pull complete
18bdd1e546d2: Pull complete
8198342c3e05: Pull complete
f56970a44fd4: Pull complete
7d255d8cc29c: Pull complete
6b76599eeb74: Pull complete
ac6a5bdae794: Pull complete
bfe65de9caf3: Pull complete
45f407574293: Pull complete
5f28b0c8228a: Pull complete
ceb4b3de72bc: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:acf3049ddc1cf7f615eb4751250881d31dccfc50752ac3a1261169b684f430cb
Status: Downloaded newer image for webdevops/apache:latest
Creating dockertest7_db_1
Creating dockertest7_apache2_1
Attaching to dockertest7_db_1, dockertest7_apache2_1
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:36:54,332 CRIT Set uid to user 0
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:36:54,332 WARN Included extra file "/opt/docker/etc/supervisor.d/apache.conf" during parsing
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:36:54,332 WARN Included extra file "/opt/docker/etc/supervisor.d/cron.conf" during parsing
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:36:54,332 WARN Included extra file "/opt/docker/etc/supervisor.d/dnsmasq.conf" during parsing
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:36:54,332 WARN Included extra file "/opt/docker/etc/supervisor.d/postfix.conf" during parsing
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:36:54,332 WARN Included extra file "/opt/docker/etc/supervisor.d/ssh.conf" during parsing
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:36:54,332 WARN Included extra file "/opt/docker/etc/supervisor.d/syslog.conf" during parsing
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:36:54,340 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:36:54,340 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
db_1       | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
db_1       | This user must also own the server process.
db_1       | 
db_1       | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
db_1       | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
db_1       | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
db_1       | 
db_1       | Data page checksums are disabled.
db_1       | 
db_1       | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
db_1       | creating subdirectories ... ok
db_1       | selecting default max_connections ... 100
db_1       | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
db_1       | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
db_1       | creating configuration files ... ok
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:36:55,345 INFO spawned: 'apached' with pid 17
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:36:55,404 INFO success: apached entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
apache2_1  | [Tue May 09 01:36:55.414084 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 17:tid 140039054796672] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
apache2_1  | [Tue May 09 01:36:55.414134 2017] [core:notice] [pid 17:tid 140039054796672] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND -D APACHE_LOCK_DIR'
db_1       | running bootstrap script ... ok
db_1       | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
db_1       | syncing data to disk ... 
db_1       | WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
db_1       | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
db_1       | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
db_1       | ok
db_1       | 
db_1       | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db_1       | 
db_1       |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
db_1       | 
db_1       | ****************************************************
db_1       | WARNING: No password has been set for the database.
db_1       |          This will allow anyone with access to the
db_1       |          Postgres port to access your database. In
db_1       |          Docker's default configuration, this is
db_1       |          effectively any other container on the same
db_1       |          system.
db_1       | 
db_1       |          Use "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" to set
db_1       |          it in "docker run".
db_1       | ****************************************************
db_1       | waiting for server to start....LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-05-09 01:36:56 UTC
db_1       | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1       | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1       | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1       |  done
db_1       | server started
db_1       | ALTER ROLE
db_1       | 
db_1       | 
db_1       | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
db_1       | 
db_1       | LOG:  received fast shutdown request
db_1       | LOG:  aborting any active transactions
db_1       | waiting for server to shut down...LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
db_1       | .LOG:  shutting down
db_1       | LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1       |  done
db_1       | server stopped
db_1       | 
db_1       | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db_1       | 
db_1       | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-05-09 01:36:58 UTC
db_1       | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1       | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1       | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

**Here I cancel it, cause it got stuck, and execute `docker-compose` again:**

```
docker-compose up
Starting dockertest7_db_1
Starting dockertest7_apache2_1
Attaching to dockertest7_db_1, dockertest7_apache2_1
db_1       | LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2017-05-09 01:37:00 UTC
db_1       | LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
db_1       | LOG:  invalid record length at 0/14EE238: wanted 24, got 0
db_1       | LOG:  redo is not required
db_1       | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1       | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1       | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:41:17,903 CRIT Set uid to user 0
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:41:17,903 WARN Included extra file "/opt/docker/etc/supervisor.d/apache.conf" during parsing
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:41:17,903 WARN Included extra file "/opt/docker/etc/supervisor.d/cron.conf" during parsing
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:41:17,903 WARN Included extra file "/opt/docker/etc/supervisor.d/dnsmasq.conf" during parsing
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:41:17,903 WARN Included extra file "/opt/docker/etc/supervisor.d/postfix.conf" during parsing
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:41:17,903 WARN Included extra file "/opt/docker/etc/supervisor.d/ssh.conf" during parsing
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:41:17,903 WARN Included extra file "/opt/docker/etc/supervisor.d/syslog.conf" during parsing
apache2_1  | Unlinking stale socket /.supervisor.sock
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:41:18,226 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:41:18,226 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:41:19,230 INFO spawned: 'apached' with pid 17
apache2_1  | 2017-05-09 01:41:19,307 INFO success: apached entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
apache2_1  | [Tue May 09 01:41:19.316042 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 17:tid 139733962508160] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
apache2_1  | [Tue May 09 01:41:19.316085 2017] [core:notice] [pid 17:tid 139733962508160] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND -D APACHE_LOCK_DIR'
```

Am I missing something? Maybe a basic stuff, configuration or something?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple things with this installation.

One is obviously postgres that did not start up properly, and is now left in unstable state. Following [article](http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/11/when-postgres-will-not-start.html) shows how to fix that.

For the rest, I cannot tell if you are having some incompatibility issues with systemd, or it is a consequence of the stalled db install, and then compose not starting up the dependencies (apache) properly.

Either way, I would remove all images, all temporary files, and try to rebuild and restart.

Comment: Also make sure you're running the latest version of Docker. What's the output of `docker version`? Latest version of Docker supports Compose v3 file format too: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/